# How do I get the URL from the previous page used to connect to my site? Not the link

Tags: php, http, url, referer

I have tried this: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

The challenge is it only gets the link that the person clicked on to reach the next page and not the actual URL of the previous page.

It does not matter if it can be spoofed. Its not mission critical. I just need to track a percentage of the results accurately.

Comment: If it helps to know, I am trying to get the URL of the page generated for the Google query used to find my page.

Comment: I think Google won' t send the search-keyword anymore, that' s what I' ve expierienced with various piwik-installations.   http://piwik.org/faq/general/#faq_144

Comment: i have a couple of plugins for wordpress and keyword tracking that does that so there must be a way.

i think what you are talking about is that the url will not show the keyword if the person is logged in to their google account. if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->session->set_userdata('url11',"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
```

This it will work 100% use any variable in place `url1` by which you can take it at place in application and write this thing in header of the view page in php tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to primarily track google search result click-throughs you should be using [Google Analytics.](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: I am not trying to do that. I asked a specific question but thanks, I guess.

Comment: Fair enough. Thought it was a good solution given your follow up comments to the question.